# php - Wrong value in post array after submitted form

Tags: php, database, forms, file-upload

I have different containers with different forms for file upload but I can't figure out what's wrong. When I upload the file, the *$_POST* variable that I use for updating the database is wrong.

This is how I print the containers with a *while* loop:

```
echo '<div class="container-r">'.$row['name'].'<div class="im-up">
    <label for="fileup"><img src="logo/upload.png" alt="Upload file"/></label>
    <form action="uploadFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="fileup" name="fileup"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="idd" id="idd" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
    </form></div><li>'.$row['evname'].'</li></div><br><br>';
```

The value that interests me is *idd* and with *inspect element* of Firefox I can see that in all forms the *idd* value is correct (in my case I have a form with value *10* and a second form with value *11*).

The problem is that even if I use the form in which *idd* is **11**, the *idd* variable obtained in the second php file directly from the *$_POST* array is **10**.

In *uploadFile.php* I have these two lines first:

```
$id = $_POST['idd'];
var_dump($id);
```

and *$id* is always **10**, even if I come from the form with value **11**. So, what am I doing wrong? What should I check? Note that it's a simple project to learn php, it doesn't pretend to be a high level project.

**EDIT:** this is the full *uploadFile.php*

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
require 'connection.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link href="css/register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr valign="middle" align="center">
        <td class="menu" background="graphics/button.png" width="120" height="30">
            <a class="mm" href="home.php"><div>Home</div></a>
        </td>
        <td class="menu" background="graphics/button.png" width="120" height="30">
            <a class="mm" href="account.php"><div>Account</div></a>
        </td>
        <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
                    echo '<td class="menu" background="graphics/button3.png" width="120" height="30"><a class="mm" href="logout.php"><div>Logout</div></a></td>';                       
                }
                else
                    echo '<td class="menu" background="graphics/button.png" width="120" height="30"><a class="mm" href="login.php"><div>Login</div></a></td><td class="menu" background="graphics/button3.png" width="120" height="30"><a class="mm" href="register.php"><div>Registrati</div></a></td>'?>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    $id = $_POST['idd'];
    var_dump($id);
    $uploaddir = 'progr/';
    $file2 = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["fileup"]["name"]). date("h i");
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileup"]["tmp_name"], $file2)) { 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE presentation SET pres_path=? WHERE user_id LIKE ? AND id LIKE ?");
            $stmt -> bind_param('sii',$file2,$_SESSION['idLog'],$id);
            if($stmt->execute())
                echo "<br><h4>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileup"]["name"]). " was uploaded</h4>".$id;
            else
                echo mysqli_error($conn); 

    } else {
        echo "<br><h3>Uploading error</h3>";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check all <form> tags are closed, and you don't have any nested <form> elements.

Comment: remove the id attributes from these elements - or assign a unique id to each

Comment: id attributes in HTML have to be unique.

Comment: the html is invalid regardless of the id attributes - you have `<li>` tags after a div tag??

Comment: what about what you're using to update your db  with?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I added the entire file for upload

Comment: @RamRaider you are right about list item element. Anyway deleting the id attributes didn't work

Answer (score 0):

By hidden input you call   **$row['id']**    and this value you send with post

```
input type="hidden" name="idd" id="idd" value=**"'.$row['id'].'**"
```

Can you check from where you get this `.$row['id'].`

Add this to your page to see what you send with post.

```
<?php
echo '<pre> POST raport ';
print_r($_POST);  
echo '</pre>';
?>
```